# Horror short story, girl dying while on a Ferris wheel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, anthology-book

I remember the cover had a skull with either mist or fog seeping from it. There are also purple hues and shades of gray.
Somewhere on the title is the word *"centennial"*.

The book was a paperback. I read this about 5 or 6 years ago. The cover felt like it was from the 80's, but the stories felt very late 19th century to late 20th. There are maybe 10 stories in it.

The specific story I remember begins with a father and daughter riding in a truck down a long road. The daughter points out a Ferris wheel, to which the dad reluctantly brings her to.

Once at the carnival, the daughter begs to go on the Ferris wheel, to which the dad agrees, just as long as she sits in the middle of the cart. The wheel starts and he watches her go around once or twice before stepping away to smoke a cigarette.

When he returns, he can't find her. He asks the conductor to stop the ride, to which the conductor gives him a hard time, until finally agreeing to pause the wheel. Then, lightning strikes and the young girl is seen dangling from the spoke of the wheel, dead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it have been "Cavalcade" instead of "Centennial"? This sounds like "Night in Funland" from "Night in Funland And Other Stories From Literary Cavalcade"

> THEY drove slowly down the highway that cut cleanly through the
> desert, past the glittering motels with their swimming pools of pale
> blue water, past the shops of pink or green or azure adobe.
>
> ...
>
> Look, in a minute, at the next stop light, we will see the wheel, ahd
> then you will remember." . At the intersection he slowed down as the
> traffic light clicked from green to amber and then to red. "Look," he
> pointed at the rosy sky; "over there; can't you see the top of the
> Ferris wheel?" She squealed with delight; then the light changed and
> they left the shining highway
>
> ...
>
> "Amanda," he screamed again, and the attendant stopped the wheel and
> came towards him and he was no·longer smiling.
>
> ...
>
> Amanda, the father cried,
>
> ...
>
> Then he pressed his tan face against the bars and gazed with comprehending eyes at the dark figure with uplifted head outlined like a
> corpse against the spokes of the great wheel blazing in the night.

https://digitalrepository.unm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3785&context=nmq

[image]

Comment: You are amazing. YES. This is it!!! I had given it to a coworker before I left for vacation, only to come back laid off and unable to get my book back. Wow. Thank you!!!!!! I've been looking loosely for 5 years now for this.

Comment: 'Could it have been "Cavalcade" instead of "Centennial"?' — wow, that is a power guess =)

Comment: That's a cool cover!

Comment: Incidentally, are there Fantasy or Sci-Fi aspects, or is it just tragic death?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yeah I think so https://authorharoldtitus.blogspot.com/2014/10/teaching-disciple-of-devil-teaches.html